# how to programmatically change the background image on form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image

I need to change the background image of my form when i klick a button, and change it back to null again the second time it is clicked, how can i do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use BackgroundImage property:

```
form.BackgroundImage = image;
```

to hide the image:

```
form.BackgroundImage = null;
```

Put this source code to ClickButton method:

```
form.BackgroundImage = form.BackgroundImage == null ? image : null;
```

Comment: what is 'image' ?  say the image is c:\b;ah\a.png  then what how do you make image refer to that.. And what if the image is in the project resources?

Comment: Try `Image.FromFile` for example.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to set the BackgroundImage property of your form from the event handler of that button.

For example you could do it like this:

> this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"c:\Temp\image.bmp");

In order to remove the image, set the property back to null.

The image can also come from a resource.