# scroll background image in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to scroll the background image that is displayed on the panel.

I looked at [how to programmatically change the background image on form c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789967/how-to-programmatically-change-the-background-image-on-form-c) but did not get any idea.

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: @NatashaD Why do you want to scroll the image? Is it partially visible?

Comment: Does the image not scroll when the panel scrolls?

Comment: I wanted to place an image-2 on top of my current image-1. I set my image-1 as background image and made image-2 as the main image. But at same time I wanted to allow the user to scroll image-1 as well.

Comment: @Oded image scrolls when the panel scrolls before I set the same image as background image.

Comment: I still have no understanding of what is not working.

Comment: @Oded scrolling on the panel when a big background image is set with smaller main image on the panel. - scrolling does not work here.

Comment: Please update your question with all these details instead of keeping it in comments. You will have a better chance of people reading it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a control inside the panel that has the background image, and then the panel has a scroll bar which would actually move the entire control inside the panel, resulting in a moving background.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: it does make sense and I have already created a control that contains a panel and scrollbars but when I set a big image as background image I want  to scroll background image as well since in this case my foreground image is always smaller than background image.

Comment: It is done now as per following steps:
1. Set Background image as current image-1.
2. Place image-2 as main image.
3. Set main image size = image-1.